# Makefile and $(wildcard) : Using complex regex

Tags: makefile

Given the intricate relationship between `bash` and `make`, I was king of hoping that the `$(wildcard )` command would instead be a `$(globbing )` command that would at least accept `bash`'s globbing pattern such as the exclamation mark `?` or the curly brackets `{}`.

My research seems to indicate that it doesn't do anything else than expanding wildcards.

Is there any known way to use more complex 'regular expression'?

Source : [Wildcard Function on GNU.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html)

Comment: make usually uses `sh`, not `bash`. And you can use something like `$(bash -c 'echo <your_pattern_here>')`

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is no closer than that `make` expects to be supplied with a [$(SHELL)](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#Choosing-the-Shell) that is sufficiently close to `/bin/sh` in certain respects. On Windows, many people use `cmd.exe`.

You can always use [the $(shell) function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html#Shell-Function) to invoke any utility you have installed through the shell:

```
C_SOURCE_FILES = $(shell echo *.[ch])
IMAGES = $(shell find * -maxdepth 2 -type f | egrep -i '\.(gif|png|jpg)$$')
```

Whatever you please.